# Get read permissions or security related objects via salesforce API

Tags: java, salesforce

I am planning to get read access for object with following query,

```
queryResults = connection.query("SELECT Assignee.Id, Assignee.Name" +
      " FROM PermissionSetAssignment" +
      " WHERE PermissionSetId" +
      " IN (SELECT ParentId" +
      " FROM ObjectPermissions" +
      " WHERE SObjectType = GivenObjectType AND" +
      " PermissionsRead = true)");
```

This is working for most of the salesforce objects. But for security related objects such as Groups, Profiles this is not working.  (i.,e when I want to check users who can see user information, I should be able to pass GivenObjectType="User" and get all the users who can see other user's information.

Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Note: I identified following object types that doesn't have support in    ObjectPermissions.SObjectType
User, Group, Partner, Profile and Task (not a security related object)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit to answer the comment**

Profiles/Permission sets only say if you're allowed to see, edit etc. Accounts *at all*. They won't tell you if you can edit account "XYZ".

You should be looking at `AccountShare` or `UserRecordAccess` tables then. They'll provide nice flattened information for you as opposed to trying to recreate the sharing rules.

Check Daniel's answer to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7805/show-insufficient-privileges-directly-when-clicking-edit-override-not-on, should give you a good start and you'll know what keywords to search for now.

---

**Original answer**

For the setup-ish objects like Group (which also includes queues) you might have to look into the System Permissions. That one would be controlled by "[Manage Users](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_and_editing_groups.htm)" I believe. At least some of my users complain that without it they can't see who's actually a member of given queue. Access to User object is probably same thing.

You should be able to find them all in [PermissionSet](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm) object.

Partner and Task are in Master-Detail relationship I think (to Account and to any object that has "allow activities" respectively... I think). So again - I think the help is your best friend: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=partners_edit.htm, https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_tasks.htm etc.

I'm curious as to why you need it though and why you insist on querying as opposed to using describe calls such as "isAccessible" or Metadata API / Tooling API if you want to fetch it to a Java application. Queries on Profiles & related stuff were exposed fairly recently and I wouldn't be surprised if some stuff is missing / inconsistent.

Comment: Actually I want to get all the users (at once) who can see particular object instance.  i.e get all the users who can read information about myacount (instance of a account object).  If I use isAccessible() then I have to call that method several times for each users in the system.